# How to add ASN.1 extensions before signing with bouncycastle?

Tags: java, certificate, bouncycastle, signing, asn.1

Right, so I am completely stumped. Usually when I sign certificates I use an ASN.1 like below to specify specific rules, that can be used for IoT for example.

```
1.2.3.4=ASN1:SEQUENCE:seq_sect

[seq_sect]
one=SEQUENCE:do_one
two=SEQUENCE:do_two

[do_one]
field.1 = UTF8:field1/*
field.2 = UTF8:field2/*

[do_two]
field.1 = UTF8:field1/*
field.2 = UTF8:field2/*
```

I usually use a program called [xca](https://hohnstaedt.de/xca/), but in this case I have been coding with bouncycastle and have been really struggling in importing this into the X509v3CertificateBuilder. I know I should be using .addExtension, but I'm not particularly certain if I should store the rules in a .txt file or if I should store it in an array and somehow parse through it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you're using OpenSSL, which xca wraps. Only OpenSSL uses this particular text-based 'config' format for ASN.1. For BouncyCastle you'll have to write code instead, something like (not tested):

```
ASN1EncodableVector one = new ASN1EncodableVector();
one.add(new DERUTF8String("field1/*"));
one.add(new DERUTF8String("field2/*"));

// if two is really identical to one, just reuse it; otherwise do something different

ASN1EncodableVector outer = new ASN1EncodableVector();
outer.add(new DERSequence(one));
outer.add(new DERSequence(two)); // or one again

builder.addExtension (oid, critical, new DERSequence(outer));
```

Similar [How to add PrivateKeyUsage extension to a certificate using bouncycastle in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085675/how-to-add-privatekeyusage-extension-to-a-certificate-using-bouncycastle-in-java) and [Creating Custom X509 v3 Extensions in Java with Bouncy Castle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412315/creating-custom-x509-v3-extensions-in-java-with-bouncy-castle)