# How to add specific "key" to an ASN1EncodableVector in BouncyCastle?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, asn.1

So, I asked a similar question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69977176/how-to-add-asn-1-extensions-before-signing-with-bouncycastle) but the issue has since evolved. So, I'll give you a whole overview and then I'll ask the question.

Currently, I am reading from a .yml file and parsing through it. I then store the data in a HashMap<String, ArrayList  > that looks something like this:

```
[{p_table=[p_event/Name, p_fault/Name]}, 
{s_table=[s_event/Name, s_fault/Name]}, 
{r_table=[r_event/Name, r_fault/Name]}]
```

Now, I understand that if I want to create an extension with bouncycastle I first have to add all of my data into an ASN1EncodableVector. What I'm doing is using certificates to tell my IoT things what topics they can subscribe/publish/receive from. Hence, I can do something like this:

```
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry = iterator.next();
            ASN1EncodableVector vector = new ASN1EncodableVector

            for(String val : entry.getValue()) {                
                (vector).add(new DERUTF8String(val));
            }
            allowedTables.add(new DERSequence(vector));
        }
```

This will only add the values from the arraylist eg p_event/Name or p_fault/Name, is there a way for me to specify that those two DERUTF8String(s) belong to the p_table? Or is there some sort of identifier I can use when using the .add method?

So could the code change from something like this:

```
(vector).add(new DERUTF8String(val));
```

to:

```
(vector).add(new aConstructorToIdentifyWhatTheUTF8BelongsTo(entry.getKey()), new DERUTF8String(val));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest sequences, i.e. you can build one DERSequence for each entry as you are doing and then add each of them to an outer ASN1EncodableVector and make a final sequence from that. The inner sequences could contain key/val/val if the number of values is fixed at 2 as in your example. Or you could have yet another sequence to hold the values e.g.:

```
SEQUENCE {
  SEQUENCE {
    "p_table",
    SEQUENCE {
      "p_event/Name",
      "p_fault/Name",
    }
  },
  SEQUENCE {
    "s_table",
    SEQUENCE {
      "s_event/Name",
      "s_fault/Name",
      "s_other/Name",
    }
  },
  // and so on
}
```

Comment: So I'd create my DERSequence, fill it with the two values as ASN1EncoableVectors. Then add the "p_table" into another DERSequence. Add the DERSequence with the values into the one with the key and then if I have more levels I can keep on adding them into infinity?

Comment: Basically, yes.

Comment: Awesome, fingers crossed I did it right... is there some sort of way to print out the final ASN1EncodableVector to see if the structure is correct?

Comment: You should end up with a top-level DERSequence. It can be printed out using org.bouncycastle.asn1.util.ASN1Dump.dumpAsString, or you could call getEncoded on the sequence and use some other ASN.1 tool to inspect the encoding.